# altering code to resize image on upload

Tags: php

I need to alter this code to resize images over 500 kB before storing them.

```php
if(isset($_FILES['photo']))
    if(file_exists($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])){
        $file_name = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        $target_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "uploads/$newfilename";

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            $handle = fopen($target_path, "rb");
            $fsize = filesize($target_path);
            $img_contents = fread($handle, $fsize);
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the functions you might use for resizing an image: [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php). I chose this one because it has a nice diagram of how the dimension attributes work in the user contributed notes.

This is the code from that page, modified slightly to actually save it as 'simpleimage.jpg'...

```
// The file
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, 'simpleimage.jpg', 100);
```

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon. Add at least some usful description as links to Off Site resources often get broken

Comment: Edited. I mainly wanted to give the name of the PHP function, but you're right.

Comment: Thats much bettter UV